# need to execute a function at after login screen

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need to display a custom alert at the home page only once, so I used **authenticated** function in AuthenticatesUsers.php file. It's working perfectly, but the problem is vendor folder doesn't push to git:/?

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't edit in vendor folder as it would be removed if update dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change vendor files as they are meant to be installed whenever you clone repo. However, you can override authenticated method in your LoginController inside

> Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
protected function authenticated()
{

}
```